# Задание с learn.javascript.ru - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Суть задания в том, чтобы изменять строку ключа объекта.Надо убрать указанные слова (если они есть в строке);
мой код вроде как работает, но вместе с ним почему-то, если находит объект, то удаляет его и так же выводит алертом индекс, на каком нашло это слово в массиве. почему оно выводит индекс когда вызываю функцию?

```
function removeClass(obj, cls) {
    for(var key in obj){
        var arrRemowe = obj[key];
        arrTest = arrRemowe.split(' ');
        for(var i = 0;i < arrTest.length; i++){
            if(arrTest.indexOf(cls) != -1) {
                var remowe = arrTest.indexOf(cls);
                    alert(remowe);
                arrTest[remowe] = '';
                obj[key] = arrTest.join(' ');
                continue;
            }else break;
        return obj[key];
        }
    }

}


var obj = {
  className: 'open menu'
};

removeClass(obj, 'open'); // obj.className='menu'
removeClass(obj, 'blabla'); // без изменений (нет такого класса)

alert(obj.className);

obj = {
  className: 'my menu menu'
};

removeClass(obj, 'menu');
alert( obj.className ); // 'my'
```

Comment: совсем непонятно что не так с твоим кодом

Comment: [ссылка](https://pp.userapi.com/c637625/v637625582/6b00d/3GFQXaIepqk.jpg)

Comment: [ссылка](https://pp.userapi.com/c637625/v637625582/6b016/9hHwa7V3cx0.jpg)
[ссылка](https://pp.userapi.com/c637625/v637625582/6b01f/J8T2NxXwFEM.jpg)

ну и так дальше выводит еще чило 2 и уж тогда просто 'my'

Comment: для того, чтобы отредактировать вопрос используй кнопку [edit]

Comment: если ты говоришь про алерты, то ты сам вызываешь `alert(remowe);` в цикле

Comment: это жесть) все спасибо) в шоке как тупанул))